# PowerShell - Loop while MainWindowTitle not found

Tags: powershell

I am a starter to PowerShell so maybe this is a dumb question.

It is a simple script. I want to open a program that itself opens different windows. The first is just a window asking if I want to connect. Using

`[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}")`

I just confirm that I want to connect. Now the next window is tricky. It takes some time to load and I know its MainWindowTitle. What I don't want to do is to write

`Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 20000`

in order to wait long enough. Sometimes it is opened within a few seconds and sometimes it takes even longer than 20s. So I thought it would be a good idea to put something in a loop and wait for the process to be fully started. Here's what I did (and what doesn't work...):

```sh
while (!$winid) {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
  $winid = Get-Process |where {$_.MainWindowTitle -like "*windowtitle*"} |select -expand id
  write-host $winid
}
```

I have the `write-host $winid` to show the outcome of my Get-Process. But it is NULL the whole time even if the window is open for a long time.

When I stop my script and simply write

```sh
Get-Process |where {$_.MainWindowTitle -like "windowtitle"} |select -expand id
```

it works! Don't know why...

How can I let the script check if the needed window is opened and ready for some Keystrokes?

Thanks,
Tobias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentionned your script was opening the program.
If so, you can get the process handle directly using Start-Process with the -PassThru switch.

```
$MyProcess = Start-Process 'notepad.exe' -PassThru
```

A complete example:

```
$MyProcess = Start-Process 'notepad.exe' -PassThru 

While ($MyProcess.MainWindowHandle -eq 0) {
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $MyProcess.MainWindowHandle
```

This is more efficient and has the advantage if it's possible to have multiple windows with that title because you actually use the handle from the process you know you have started.

As for your specific error, I kind of got it while testing your script until I put a $winid = $null before the while to reset the variable. I think if you actually call the script, $winid will be null every time, but if you are testing this script through an IDE, then the variable might stick between execution, meaning it would work the first time but would never enter the while loop afterward because $winid value would still be set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The app I am opening is basically creating a remote connection. While doing that it opens the first window - which would work with your code. But that window is directly closed again when I choose "connect" and thus I get a new process id. I found out that the window name of the new window I was trying to catch somehow doesn't get its correct naming until my script is done. I found the temporary name and added it in my script. Now it works. But as your answer applies to 99% of opening apps and really helps for other things I'd like to do I will mark it as correct!

Comment: And thanks for the ForegroundColor tip in your reply! Always learning...